# Sync firebase database with sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-sqlite

I'm using sqlite to store data in my app, i would like to sync my database with firebase so that i can do modify data  from firebase and insert it into my database without updating the app. Any suggestions how can i do that.

Comment: What is the purpose of using a Sqlite database?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to sync **Firebase** with your local database. **Firebase** provides you **SDK** to perform read/write operations in your database. You might only need to update your application if there is a schema change. That too can be achieved without keeping the computation logic in the Cloud and instead call **Cloud Functions** for cases where you know there are going to be a lot of schema changes.

Firebase provides you really well documented APIs and code samples. You can refer the following links for more information:

[Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs) -- SDKs here

[Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) -- For cloud computation

[Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) -- Database for realtime transfer, can be costly for high usage. Generally used for PoC or low traffic projects

[Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) -- Upgraded version of Realtime DB. Generally used for high traffic.